# Converting Date+Time Formats

Tags: timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I need to convert the following format into a new format using NSDateFormatter.

'Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:16:00 -0700'.

I tried using "aaa, dd bbb YYYY HH:MM:SS ZHHMM" as format, but it doesn't work; it gives me a date way in the past.

I also need to convert it into the Eastern Time Zone when creating a new date.

The code I used is the following one:

```
NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:SS"];
```

Comment: Please show the code that you tried to use, in as complete a form as you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this string down into the various portions:

Fri, 25 Mar 2011 10:16:00 -0700 becomes:

- Fri: abbreviated day of the week
- 25: potentially zero-padded day of the month
- Mar: abbreviated month
- 2011: year
- 10: potentially zero-padded hour (in 24-hour format because there is no AM/PM)
- 16: potentially zero-padded minute
- 00: zero-padded second
- -0700: time zone offset

Now let's look at the [date format patterns that `NSDateFormatter` supports](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns):

- abbreviated day of the week: `EEE`
- zero-padded day of the month: `dd`
- abbreviated month: `MMM`
- year: `y`
- zero-padded hour (24-hour): `HH`
- zero-padded minute: `mm`
- zero-padded second: `ss`
- time zone offset: `ZZZ`

Thus, your format string should be: `@"EEE, dd MMM y HH:mm:ss ZZZ"`.